# User with FULL CONTROL Unable to Access List Settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions

I'm trying to be able to access the settings for a sharepoint list. I believe I literally have all the permissions I could possibly get (full control at the top most level of the site), but the list permissions is still disabled. When I request access to the list settings, the request is just for the generic multi site, not for the list itself. I'm not sure what else I can do. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have site collection administrator permissions? Try opening list settings using administrator permissions & then you can check who all are having permissions on list (if inheritance is broken).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that you have full control for the site collection, but you cannot go to list settings for a particular list.

It may be caused by the list has unique permission. Try to grant list permission for yourself by using PowerShell.

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescenttech.sharepoint.com/sites/Marketing"
$ListName ="Projects"
$UserID="Peter@TheCrescentTech.com"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Break Permission Inheritance of the List
Set-PnPList -Identity $ListName -BreakRoleInheritance -CopyRoleAssignments
 
#Grant permission on List to User
Set-PnPListPermission -Identity $ListName -AddRole "Full Control" -User $UserID
```